# Ayuda clase offset Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, offset

Tengo dos columnas que quiero que funcionen así:

cuando estén en tamaños md y lg midan [9   | 3]
 y cuando sea SM la primera clumna mida 12 y la segunda pase abajo y tenga  4 de offset y sea de tamaño 8

En SM funciona correctamente pero en tamaños grandes sigue haciendo el offset el cual no quiero que lo haga, ¿el código está bien así?

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 " id="agm">
          <h2>Titulo</h2>
          <hr class="primary">
          <p>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde perferendis et reiciendis ipsam iste rerum culpa. Sequi nihil tempora ut quisquam consectetur aspernatur temporibus consequuntur error molestiae. Eos ducimus doloremque fugit dolorum voluptatibus molestias quibusdam officia, voluptatum molestiae et, necessitatibus voluptas laudantium deleniti animi. Ex beatae tempore magni illo officia odit rerum autem saepe, voluptatem nobis voluptatibus minus ratione perferendis blanditiis harum, corporis totam hic fugit at laboriosam optio incidunt. Incidunt aliquid alias, voluptatum sunt deleniti reprehenderit explicabo suscipit odit modi amet aut sint cupiditate impedit maiores est quae eius. Commodi fugit sequi laborum veniam labore eligendi  </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-12 text-center">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde perferendis et reiciendis ipsam iste rerum culpa. Sequi nihil tempora ut quisquam consectetur aspernatur temporibus consequuntur error molestiae. Eos ducimus doloremque fugit dolorum 
      </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: has probado de incluir col-XX-offset-0, donde XX sea md y lg?

Comment: También recuerda que Bootstrap es `mobile first` por lo que sino sobre escribes una clase xs para otros tamaños, estos también obtendrán los atributos de xs, lo mismo pasa con sm, y md

Comment: Muchas gracias no sabia el offset-0 funcionó perfecto

Comment: De nada, para eso estamos!

Comment: Mi respuesta es correcta... ( ._.)

Comment: @kerunaru no se como darte puntos recien inicio en esta web tampoco me deja contestar a tu respuesta, muy amable por tu consejo y tu enseñanza tu respuesta es correcta Gracias!

Comment: @AndresDevelop puedes darle puntos dandole a la flecha de arriba en su respuesta, y si te ayudó a solucionar tu problema, darle al tick que aparecerá debajo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas ponerle `col-lg-offset-0` para que no haga el *offset* en tamaños grandes.

Ten en cuenta que lo que defines usando las clases es **a partir de qué tamaño** (xs, sm, md, lg) en adelante se aplica el estilo (en este caso offset-0).